# How to interpolate lat long points in time series using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a pandas data frame with the a datetime field, an ID field and columns for latitude and longitude. It describes moving points over time:

```
         Date                               ID           Lat       Lon
2017-07-03 00:03:43  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  39.90459 -75.12544
2017-07-03 00:06:49  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  39.91282 -75.17551
2017-07-03 00:09:56  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  39.93888 -75.19702
2017-07-03 00:13:03  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  39.96759 -75.18911
2017-07-03 00:16:09  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  40.00141 -75.19462
```

My data frame has multiple IDs, each describing a different object. What I'm trying to do is for each ID, fill in the 'gaps' in the Date fields by adding rows for each second, as well as an interpolation of where the lat long point has moved, assuming it travels as the crow flies between points (and not accounting for earth's curvature)

What I have so far is:

```
idlist = df['ID'].unique() #create list of all ids
for x in idlist:
    temp = df.loc[df['ID']==x] #iterate of smaller sub-dataframe for each ID
    temp['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['Date'])
    mindate = temp['Date'].min()
    maxdate = temp['Date'].max()
    idx = pd.date_range(mindate, maxdate,freq='s') #create new second index
    temp = temp.set_index('Date')
    temp = temp.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    temp.loc[temp['ID']==0, 'TripID'] = x
    print(temp)
    break
```

Which gets me part of the way there.

```
                                             TripID       Lat       Lon
2017-07-03 00:03:43  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  39.90459 -75.12544
2017-07-03 00:03:44  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3   0.00000   0.00000
2017-07-03 00:03:45  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3   0.00000   0.00000
2017-07-03 00:03:46  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3   0.00000   0.00000
2017-07-03 00:03:47  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3   0.00000   0.00000
...
2017-07-03 00:16:08  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3   0.00000   0.00000
2017-07-03 00:16:09  f2d8c21d593adcb5423127923d63c7b3  40.00141 -75.19462
```

I need to work out how to fill in the Lat and Lon positions where they equal 0, so that the ID seems to move in a straight line between the points I have data for.

This is the part I am unsure about. Any insight would help.
Once I know how to do that I can append all my finished temp dataframes to an output.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are looking for the method `.ffill()`. To prepare your data, you will have to set the values on `data['Lat']` and `data['Lon']` equal to `NA`, so that the values can forward-fill.

```
data.loc[data['Lat'] == 0, 'Lat'] = None
data.loc[data['Lon'] == 0, 'Lon'] = None #fill NA where equal to zero

data['Lat'] = data['Lat'].ffill()
data['Lon'] = data['Lon'].ffill() #conversly, data['Lon'].fillna(method = 'ffill') should work
```

This should give the desired output - please comment if I misunderstood the question. For pandas API, refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clearer. What I'm looking for is for the NA values filled in as if the id is travelling between the two known locations.
The NA points halfway chronologically between the two points should also be halfway geographically.